# Check if empty not working for me

Tags: php, sql

I want to check if a row value from my database is NULL or empty so I did the following:

```
$existcheck           = "
    SELECT *
    FROM snm_content";
    $existcheckcon      = $conn->query($existcheck);
    $existcheck       = $existcheckcon->fetch_assoc();

    if((!empty($existcheck['plaats'])) AND (!empty($existcheck['straat']))){
      echo 'vol';
    }else{
      $vultable           = "
      ALTER TABLE snm_content
      ADD (straat varchar(255) NULL,
      plaats varchar(255) NULL)";
      $vultablecon      = $conn->query($vultable);
      $vultable       = $vultablecon->fetch_assoc();


      $updatetable            = "
      UPDATE snm_content
      SET straat = '".$straatnaam."', plaats = '".$bedrijven['plaats']."'";
      $updatetablecon       = $conn->query($updatetable);
      $updatetable       = $updatetablecon->fetch_assoc();
    }
```

But I get the following message:

> There was an error running the query [Duplicate column name 'straat']

Both `straat` and `plaats` in `snm_content` are all filled with `NULL`.

So why does it get to the else statement if the values are NULL?

I should mention, this code is inside a while loop from another query.

Comment: `Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.` and with loose typing, NULL is falsey, like a 0 or an empty string.... see the [tables on this page of the PHP Docs](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: I think you wanna check if a column exist rather than empty?

Comment: Which particular SQL dialect?  *(Hover your mouse over the `SQL` tag that you added to this question.)*

Comment: @twan some time below 5.5 php version not supported !empty.please try 
 "!=" instead of !empty or use isset function.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the column exist not if column have a data so you have to do like this :

```
$existcheck           = "DESC snm_content";
$existcheckcon      = $conn->query($existcheck);
$existcheck       = $existcheckcon->fetch_assoc();

if((!empty($existcheck['plaats'])) AND (!empty($existcheck['straat']))){
  echo 'vol';
}else{
  $vultable           = "
  ALTER TABLE snm_content
  ADD (straat varchar(255) NULL,
  plaats varchar(255) NULL)";
  $vultablecon      = $conn->query($vultable);
  $vultable       = $vultablecon->fetch_assoc();


  $updatetable            = "
  UPDATE snm_content
  SET straat = '".$straatnaam."', plaats = '".$bedrijven['plaats']."'";
  $updatetablecon       = $conn->query($updatetable);
  $updatetable       = $updatetablecon->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that *assume* Oracle?

Comment: I guess he use MySql.